# Android scrollview with up or down arrow

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

Is there a way to make up or down arrows appear if there is more text left above the current view or below the current view? It's not very obvious in my Android application that there is more text below the current view but I want the user to know that there is more text below the current view. How do I make arrows appear this?

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgnd" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant1"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="1"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant1" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant2"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="2"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant2" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant3"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="19"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant3" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant4"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="3"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant4" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant5"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="10"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant5" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant6"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="7"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant6" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant7"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="15"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant7" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant8"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="13"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant8" />
              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/awesome_constant9"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:onClick="doSomething"
                  android:tag ="16"
                  android:text="@string/awesome_constant9" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may overide onScrollChanged which can tell you if your content is off screen
In there you can

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

       View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
       int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));
       if (diff > 0) { //then not at bottom

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way to go about this is just to have a drop shadow or **fading edge** on the scroll view, which should be enabled by default. You can set the property by using `android:requiresFadingEdge` in XML.

[image: Fading edge]

If you want arrows then you will have to overlay them yourself by adding two images (for example, in a `FrameLayout` or something); there is nothing really built in.